# Availability of Dutch for the Watson TTS service on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, text-to-speech, ibm-watson

I am building an application where there is a need for have Text To Speech.
The primary users will be Dutch, in the beginning. So I am looking for TTS with Dutch support.
Google Translate offer Dutch as an alternative, but I would like to use the TTS Watson service on Bluemix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Text-to-Speech documentation](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/text-to-speech/), the service supports plain text in the following languages:

- English
- French
- German
- Italian
- Japanese
- Spanish
- Brazilian Portuguese

Unfortunately, Dutch is not a supported language for input. We are always looking for ways to improve out services so feel free to submit a [IBM Bluemix Idea](https://ibm-bluemix.uservoice.com/forums/311383-ibm-bluemix-ideas?cm_mc_sid_50200000=1458943039&cm_mc_uid=01507638680114570417219) for future consideration by Bluemix/Watson Project Management.